# Source of Greg LeMond's quote, “It never gets easier; you just go faster.”

Tags: tour-de-france, bike-culture

This is a question I asked previously on the [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18766/source-of-greg-lemonds-quote-it-never-gets-easier-you-just-go-faster) site a month ago, but no one has been able to answer it.  The Bicycles Stack Exchange seems to be mostly questions about bikes, but I'm hoping in addition to gearheads, there are cycling fanatics here who might be able to help me answer my question.

I'm writing an article about cycling and I want to include a well know quote from the professional cyclist Greg LeMond (the first and only American to win the Tour de France).  The quote is:

> It never gets easier, you just get faster.

This quote is widely used, but I'm having trouble finding the original source.  I would like to properly attribute it in my citations.  For example in the book about LeMond's '89 Tour win, *The Comeback* by Daniel de Visé, the author uses the quote as the opening epigraph.  *The Comeback* includes an extensive notes section where Visé attributes his sources, but I don't see any source for the LeMond quote.  Many other books about cycling use this quote too, but likewise don't include the original source.

This quote shows up all over the Internet too.  For example the web site [Velominati](https://www.velominati.com/) uses LeMond's quote for their tenth rule without attributing the source.  Also consistent with how the quote is used, the wording varies.  The version used by the Velominati substitues *go* for *get*:

> It never gets easier, you just go faster.

Anyone know where this quote originated?

Comment: I've also seen the similar phrase "It doesn't get easier, you just get stronger" which seems to be everywhere, and isn't really ever attributed to a person.

Comment: Not the first American to win the TdF, but the ONLY American to win the Tour. That said.

Comment: @Scribbler it would be nice if you can correct your question, as per Carel comment. Lance Armstrong and Floyd wins at the Tour are not valid.

Comment: @EarlGrey Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Greg LeMond, Mark Hom (2014). “The Science of Fitness: Power, Performance, and Endurance”, p.122, Academic Press

according to the site https://www.azquotes.com/author/8602-Greg_LeMond .

Then [google books preview](https://books.google.ch/books?id=PCtBBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q&f=false) offers the excerpt, where the origin of the sentence are still unclear, but it looks like it was actually said by Greg LeMond in the past, discussing the merits of training becaming easy when you are a pro (no, it's not).

Comment: This is close, thanks.  At least it is a book co-authored by LeMond, so it gives credibility to the authenticity of the quote.  I may end up using this in my citations, but I'm still holding out hope for the original source.

Comment: @Scribbler you know, Greg LeMond is still alive, according to his wikipedia page.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_LeMond  If you want a source better than his book, maybe seek a direct contact ?  Maybe invite him to join SE Bicycles.